# Letter of Approved Leave

Tags: visas, schengen, denmark

I'm planning to reapply for a Schengen visa for Denmark because my application before was refused. I'm not sure if I can submit a letter of approved leave right now. At the moment, I don't want it known that I'm reapplying. If the application is in process, can I latter add a replacement for the letter of approved leave?

Comment: Why cant you get a letter of approved leave...?

Comment: My application is still on process and I dont want others to know that I am re applying for another visa. So, I cannot ask yet. Is there any another way?

Answer (score 2):

The consulate needs to know that you have a job to return to after your trip.

If you can't even tell your employer that you're *planning* a vacation, it is difficult to imagine that they would take it kindly if you suddenly *go* on one.

And if you're willing to go an a holiday which is likely to cost you a job, then it is very hard to imagine that going on a holiday is your real motivation -- and much easier to think you're probably looking to immigrate illegally.

Once this suspicion has been raised, there are not many good substitutes for a declaration from your employer that you would not lose your job by going on the trip.  Something like a binding offer to start a *different* job after you come home might do.

Comment: Can my immediate Supervisor or the Branch Head Officer sign my letter?

Comment: @user59540: Perhaps, depending on the local business culture in your home country. If your employer is large enough to have a formal HR/payroll function, getting a letter from them is probably most likely to be accepted -- but in a pinch, a declaration from the manager who is responsibe for accepting/denying your vacation requests may do too.